# Jupyter notebook: need to run a cell even though close the tab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

My notebook is located on a server, which means that the kernel will still run even though I close the notebook tab. I was thus wondering if it was possible to let the cell running by itself while closing the window? As the notebook is located on a server the kernel will not stop running...

I tried to read previous questions but could not find an answer. Any idea on how to proceed? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can make open a new file and write outputs to it. I think that's the best that you can do.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the cell before closing the tab it will continue to run once the tab has been closed. However, the output will be lost (anything using print functions to stdout or plots which display inline) unless it is written to file.

Comment: No, when I run the cell, close the tab and reopen it afterwards, the cell is not running anymore...

Comment: The cell will still be running in the background but you cannot reconnect to that instance of the cell with the interface. Hence why output must be to file. As far as I know there is no way to reconnect the interface to that running cell. See: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2446

Answer (score 0):

Jupyter has cell magic that can solve this

###### Simple solution:

`%%capture foobar` allows you to capture the cell's stdout into a variable, and you can print it with `foobar.show()` in the same cell.

This does however stop you from seeing the output of the cell while it's running, so there is a solution to this by making a custom magic startup script.

###### Alternative solution:

[How to simultaneously capture and display ipython (jupyter notebook) cell output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64572585/how-to-simultaneously-capture-and-display-ipython-jupyter-notebook-cell-output)

I made a file in `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/` and named it `00-tee.py` with the content being the code at the bottom. Give it executable permissions, then when you load a kernel, it automatically executes this code on startup.

Now you can use `%%tee foobar` and show the output by using `foobar()` so that the output will still be displayed on the screen while running, and you can recall it after reopening the session.

```python
from IPython import get_ipython
from IPython.core import magic_arguments
from IPython.core.magic import register_cell_magic
from IPython.utils.capture import capture_output

@magic_arguments.magic_arguments()
@magic_arguments.argument('output', type=str, default='', nargs='?',
    help="""The name of the variable in which to store output.
    This is a utils.io.CapturedIO object with stdout/err attributes
    for the text of the captured output.
    CapturedOutput also has a show() method for displaying the output,
    and __call__ as well, so you can use that to quickly display the
    output.
    If unspecified, captured output is discarded.
    """
)
@magic_arguments.argument('--no-stderr', action="store_true",
    help="""Don't capture stderr."""
)
@magic_arguments.argument('--no-stdout', action="store_true",
    help="""Don't capture stdout."""
)
@magic_arguments.argument('--no-display', action="store_true",
    help="""Don't capture IPython's rich display."""
)
@register_cell_magic
def tee(line, cell):
    args = magic_arguments.parse_argstring(tee, line)
    out = not args.no_stdout
    err = not args.no_stderr
    disp = not args.no_display
    with capture_output(out, err, disp) as io:
        get_ipython().run_cell(cell)
    if args.output:
        get_ipython().user_ns[args.output] = io
    
    io()
```