# How to simultaneously capture and display ipython (jupyter notebook) cell output?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter

How do you capture the cell output in `jupyter notebook` while simultaneously showing the results? I do not want to wait for everything to finish and then running a variable.show().

[image]

Comment: Yeah I also need to both save the results in a variable and see the results as its printed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jupyter notebook show and capture output at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49524626/jupyter-notebook-show-and-capture-output-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I adapted the following custom cell magic from the [implementation](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/0e4d6390b2174fb1b352a082b72ad387ae696e87/IPython/core/magics/execution.py#L1446) of the built-in `%%capture`:

```py
from io import StringIO
import sys

from IPython.core import magic_arguments
from IPython.core.magic import Magics, cell_magic, magics_class
from IPython.utils.capture import CapturedIO


class Tee(StringIO):
    def __init__(self, initial_value='', newline='\n', stream=None):
        self.stream = stream
        super().__init__(initial_value, newline)
    
    def write(self, data):
        if self.stream is not None:
            self.stream.write(data)
        
        super().write(data)


class capture_and_print_output(object):
    stdout = True
    stderr = True
    display = True
    
    def __init__(self, stdout=True, stderr=True, display=True):
        self.stdout = stdout
        self.stderr = stderr
        self.display = display
        self.shell = None
    
    def __enter__(self):
        from IPython.core.getipython import get_ipython
        from IPython.core.displaypub import CapturingDisplayPublisher
        from IPython.core.displayhook import CapturingDisplayHook
        
        self.sys_stdout = sys.stdout
        self.sys_stderr = sys.stderr
        
        if self.display:
            self.shell = get_ipython()
            if self.shell is None:
                self.save_display_pub = None
                self.display = False
        
        stdout = stderr = outputs = None
        if self.stdout:
            stdout = sys.stdout = Tee(stream=sys.stdout)
        if self.stderr:
            stderr = sys.stderr = Tee(stream=sys.stderr)
        if self.display:
            self.save_display_pub = self.shell.display_pub
            self.shell.display_pub = CapturingDisplayPublisher()
            outputs = self.shell.display_pub.outputs
            self.save_display_hook = sys.displayhook
            sys.displayhook = CapturingDisplayHook(shell=self.shell,
                                                   outputs=outputs)
        
        return CapturedIO(stdout, stderr, outputs)
    
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        sys.stdout = self.sys_stdout
        sys.stderr = self.sys_stderr
        if self.display and self.shell:
            self.shell.display_pub = self.save_display_pub
            sys.displayhook = self.save_display_hook


@magics_class
class CustomMagics(Magics):
    @magic_arguments.magic_arguments()
    @magic_arguments.argument('output', type=str, default='', nargs='?')
    @magic_arguments.argument('--no-stderr', action='store_true')
    @magic_arguments.argument('--no-stdout', action='store_true')
    @magic_arguments.argument('--no-display', action='store_true')
    @cell_magic
    def tee(self, line, cell):
        args = magic_arguments.parse_argstring(self.tee, line)
        out = not args.no_stdout
        err = not args.no_stderr
        disp = not args.no_display
        with capture_and_print_output(out, err, disp) as io:
            self.shell.run_cell(cell)
        if args.output:
            self.shell.user_ns[args.output] = io
```

You need to register this cell magic, usually either in your startup profile or by defining it as an extension you load later, for example:

```py
from IPython import get_ipython

get_ipython().register_magics(CustomMagics)
```

Now you can use it as follows:

```py
>>> %%tee output
    print(42)
42
>>> output.show()
42
```

One thing to note: it will capture rich outputs as the original `%%capture` does, but it won't print them in the original cell. If that's important, you may find some way to adapt the above to include rich outputs, perhaps by subclassing `CapturingDisplayPublisher/Hook`.

Comment: Consider to add io() in the end of tee() method. This will show errors tracebacks.

Answer (score 1):

This one works perfectly for me :

[Jupyter notebook show and capture output at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49524626/jupyter-notebook-show-and-capture-output-at-the-same-time)

It will show the output while simultaneously capturing it, and one can show the captured output in the next cell.